# What is Codeigniter, CakePHP, Laravel, Zend and Symfony?

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, cakephp, zend-framework

I am a PHP developer and I want to increase my knowledge. So I am trying to understand some online scripts. I see some folders named ( Zend, Symfony.. etc ) and I read about code igniter.

However, I still didn't understand anything of what I want to know.

- What is and when to use each of them?
- What are the features they provide?
- With which should I start with?

  Codeigniter, CakePHP, Laravel, Zend and Symfony frameworks

I know this may be a duplicate question but I really need a complete answer that I really did not find.

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think stackoverflow community can give you correct answer for your question. May be you should tried to understand some basic features of each MVC framework. Each framework has pros and cons. It's depend on how you want to implement your system. This is no right or wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should start from learning MVC pattern that is used in all of mentioned frameworks, if you're not already know what it is.

The next thing are requirements - what you need or what you expect from framework? There are some things that frameworks cannot do. You can check and compare what each framework can or cannot do for you. Note every part that you discovered.

Some frameworks are easy to start, others need advanced knowledge. Check the examples in docs.

Next step could be your own testing to code something.

This is really too general question, that was asked and answered many times not only here (at stackoverflow), but at many other websites too. Just add some important keywords and search. All in your hands.

Comment: thanks a lot this is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

They are php frameworks

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5

https://www.codeigniter.com/

Just google tutorials for (one of the frameworks) and work your way through them. There are plenty of resources out there.

I would start with codeigniter first since the learning curve is less steep